# Is there any reason in slurm not running more than a certain number of nodes?

Tags: slurm

I want to run about 400 jobs in GCP-slurm from about 2,000 arrays.

The slurm settings and slurm.config settings in my bash file are as follows.

run.sh

```
#SBATCH -o ./out/vs.%j.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH -W
```

slurm.config

```
MaxArraySize=50000
MaxJobCount=50000

#COMPUTE NODE
NodeName=DEFAULT CPUs=16 RealMemory=63216 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=node-0-[0-599] State=CLOUD
```

Currently, 100 nodes are being used for work other than that task.

If you proceed with this task, only about 130-150 node tasks in total are executed and the rest are not executed.

Are there any additional parameters that need to be set?

-- additional error log

```
[2022-06-20T01:18:41.294] error: get_addr_info: getaddrinfo() failed: Name or service not known
[2022-06-20T01:18:41.294] error: slurm_set_addr: Unable to resolve “node-333"
[2022-06-20T01:18:41.294] error: fwd_tree_thread: can't find address for host node-333, check slurm.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the additional error.

https://groups.google.com/g/slurm-users/c/y-QZKDbYfIk

I referred to the article, and you can edit slurcmtld.service / slurmd.service / slurmdbd.service.

```
network.target -> network-online.target
```

However, the maximum number of execution nodes is still maintained.